# What are Local and Global Inpainting Techniques in Image Processing?

Tags: image-processing, inverse-problem, image-restoration

- Is Diffusion-based inpaiting Local or Global?
- Is Pixel-based inpaiting Local or Global?
- Is Patch-based inpaiting Local or Global?
- Can Local-diffusion be used inside Patch-based in-painting problems of Image Processing?
- Or, three of them can be applied separately to operate on the same type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Usually one could divide the methods according to:

1. Global Method
   The function optimized is all over the image with no local data.
   Namely it finds best solution involving all pixels.
   Diffusion Based is usually iterative method to solve such a Global model.
2. Local Method
   The optimization function is local for a group of patches and holes.
   Most "Patch" based methods are local in their nature.

In practice, state of the art methods combine both approaches.
Namely global regulator over a local optimization function or the other way around.

Comment: By the way, if you are into Image Processing, please follow this proposal - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/image-processing-and-computer-vision. Please upvote questions with less than 10 points.